# Curl - Printing value using grep

Tags: curl, search, awk, grep

I am fairly new at this curl scripting and I am looking for a way to paste a text from a token like value when I hit a specific site.

Currently I have:

```
echo $a_opensite | grep -E -o 'value=\".*==.*' | awk '{print $1}' > 
                  /Users/MZComputer/Downloads/10Step/VIEWSTATE_file;
```

which writes the value below in a file called:

```
VIEWSTATE_file****value="bdC7M0jCKxJNSfHjUVv+4MMt3/ysSLviYkIQnnpntK3qNCarg7H012UIllu+XBDepbWYWktNdf3EBgd3xd0...UVv"****
```

BUT the text `value="` is what I am able to use to get the correct token. However, I do not want to include the `value="...."` in the file, just want to include the text within the quotation marks - excluding the quotation marks themselves.

Any ideas how I can achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line:

```
echo $a_opensite | grep -E -o 'value=\".==.' | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/value="\([^"]*\)"/\1/' > /Users/MZComputer/Downloads/10Step/VIEWSTATE_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU grep, I'd use its `-P` option and Perl-style lookbehind/lookahead expressions. For example:

```
$ echo 'foo value="something interesting" bar' | grep -Po '(?<=value=\").*?(?=\")'
something interesting
```

The interesting bits are:

1. `(?=\")` -- this is a *lookahead* expression. It matches the empty string iff it is followed by the specified regex, in this case `\"`. In the example above it'll match the empty string just before `" bar` at the end of the supplied input.
2. `(?<=value=\")` -- this is a *lookbehind* expression. It matches the empty string iff it is preceded by the specified regex, in this case `value=\"` In the example above, it'll match the empty string just before `something interesting`.
3. `.*?` matches any sequence of characters *non-greedily*, which is to say that if the line reads `value="stuff" garbage="more stuff"` it'll match just `stuff` and not `stuff" garbage="more stuff`.

Combined with the `-o` option, this will isolate the string between `value="` and the next `"`.